# How to generate embedding for Image Dataset with multiple features?

Tags: computer-vision, embeddings

My dataset has Jewellery images. The jewellery is of 4 types:

1. Type
2. Color
3. Shape
4. Material

Now I am aware of converting images to embeddings. I need to group similar images like two plain gold rings are similar but "plain gold ring with heart shape" is not similar to "plain gold ring with moon shape"

Which model should I use to do this?

What will be my last layer? Will it be the four characteristics, or shall I lay out the number of combinations such as Plain Gold ring, Heart shape gold ring, etc. Lets assume the poosible combinations come out to be 50. Then my last layer will have 50 outputs?

Please throw light on this.

Also a big problem is that the dataset is completely unlabeled. Is there any way I can group similar images unsupervised style?

Thanks